# Validation of the Time according to the shifts table

Tags: c#, validation, time

I have a TblShift that contains the IdShift - ShiftName and start and end time of the shift, and a field that specifies the end hour at the next day. For example, 23 today until 7 days later.

I have a TblTimelyHeader table that holds  Date and shifts (IdShift)

i have a TblTimelyContent table that I Insert on my  includes the machine ID, the TblTimelyHeaderID, the start time and production end hours
Looking for the easiest and best way to validate the start and end hour. My problem is more on shifts like today's 23 to 7 days later.

TblShift:

```
ShiftId         int Key
ShiftName       nvarchar(50)
ShiftTimeBegin  time(7)
ShiftTimeEnd    time(7)
ShiftEndDay     bit
```

TblTimelyHeader:

```
TimelyHeaderId  int Key
Date            DateTime
Shift_Id        int(Foreign Key)
```

TimelyContentId:

```
TimelyContentId     int Key
TimelyHeader_Id     int(Foreign Key)
Mashin_Id           int(Foreign Key)
TimeBeginTimely     time(7)
TimeEndTimely       time(7)
```

Comment: Share your table structure in well format. And share your efforts.

Comment: Edit your question and add data structure in question instead of comment.